# How to compare each digit from two integers from the users c++

Tags: c++, integer, compare

I'm currently making a program which asks the user for the input for two integers and compare if they are correct. I need help coding this program. (sorry I am new to c++).

For example, this is my desired output.

Enter your positive integer: 123

Enter your positive integer: 124

number 1: 123

number 2: 124

number of comparison: 3

3 -- 4 (incorrect)

2 -- 2 (correct)

1 -- 1 (correct)

so far i have this code:

```
void twoInt()
{
int first, second;


cout << "\n\nEnter your positive integer : ";
cin >> first;
cout << "\nEnter your positive integer : ";
cin >> second;

cout << "\n\nNumber 1: " << setw(10) << first;
cout << "\nNumber 2: " << setw(10) << second;

// how do i compare each digit that user has entered 
//through keyboard and compare them to first and second integer variable




fflush(stdin);
cin.get();


}
```

which in-built function should i use to compare by using a for loop?

Thanks in advance! Any tips and help will be much appreciated!

Comment: HINT: `123%10==3` and `124%10==4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void twoInt()
 {
    int first, second;
    int fDigit;
    int sDigit;

    cout << "\n\nEnter your positive integer : ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "\nEnter your positive integer : ";
    cin >> second;

    cout << "\n\nNumber 1: " << setw(10) << first;
    cout << "\nNumber 2: " << setw(10) << second;
    while ( (first ) && (second ))
    {
      fDigit = first % 10;
      first  = first/10;
      sDigit = second % 10;
      second = second / 10;

      if (fDigit == sDigit )
      {
        printf(" %d - % d Correct\n",fDigit,sDigit);
      }
      else
      {
        printf(" %d - % d  Incorrect\n",fDigit,sDigit);
      }

    }
    fflush(stdin);

    cin.get();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A rough outline:

Use a recursive function.

In the function, get the last digit of each number.

```
d1 = N1 % 10
d2 = N2 % 10
```

Compare them and produce suitable output.

Then call the function again with the rest of the number:

```
N1 = N1 / 10
N2 = N2 / 10
```

Stop recursion when either `N1` or `N2` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both numbers to strings with std::to_string()
Compare with the algorithm that you prefer: std::equal() or std::mismatch()

Why don't you compare them directly as intergers?

Answer (score 0):

Step back for a moment -- do you actually care that the user has entered *integers*? It looks more like what you care about is that the user has entered *strings of digits*, and that you want to do an analysis on the *strings of digits*.

If you actually read his input as a *string of digits*, then, the program will be more straightforward.